# Can you dynamically enqueue and dequeue with React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an object of game players with my React state. I want to do it dynamically so I don't have to hardcode the amount of players able to play. Is there a way to achieve this state change with a JS FIFO queue?

In my case, I'm attempting to build a queue of players, and to dequeue each player within state after the player's turn. Players would need the ability to enqueue to the back of the line if they make the right score.

I'm not sure if I can use a function, like `dequeue()`, within setState? If I can't do that, would I just build my queue object before setting state, and then pass that result into my setState?

Also, I don't know if React state allows the component's state object to be dynamically changed? If I had a queue of multiple players within state like:

```
playerQueue = {
   1: {
        id: 123,
        score: 5,
        queued: false,
        currentTurn: false
        },
   2: {
        id: 237,
        score: 7,
        queued: true,
        currentTurn: false
      },
   3: {
        id: 488,
        score: null,
        queued: true,
        currentTurn, true
      }
```

Does state allow me to dynamically add as many players I wanted, following that object structure?

Here's roughly what I have now. The highestScore setState works properly. I'm not sure how to do the player queue. I'm essentially updating the scoreboard. I also need this action to change my state to the next player's turn.

```
if (score > tableHighScore) {

          this.setState(prevState => ({
            highestScore: {
              score: score, 
              player: player,
              tableHighScore: score
            },
            //playerQueue: {
            //  ...prevState, dequeue();
            //}
          }));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Map instead of plain object

```
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', { id: 12, ... })
m.set('key2', { id: 12, ... })
// get the first entry
const firstEntry = m.entries().next().value // [ 'key1', {} ]
m.delete(firstEntry[0])
// add to the map 
m.set('key3', {})
```

and every time you want to modify the map, you must clone it first

```
const newMap = new Map(existingMap)
```